# Password protecting a directory

Tags: apache-2.2, password

Password protecting a directory seems like a [chore](http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/password-protect-directory.shtml) using `.htaccess` file. Is there no simpler way to do this?

Comment: What  is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have a directory with some personal info that only I should be able to access via a browser.

Comment: Well no. That problem you have is already solved with `.htaccess`, as you wrote. Do you have a specific .htaccess that is too complicated? Can you provide a sample of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, that is almost dead simple once you understand it.  Most of the other options are far more complex.

Keep in mind that you don't actually have to use an htaccess file if you have access to the Apache configuration.  Just put the same settings in a your main configuration.  But that really isn't any simpler, you are just modifying a different file.

Comment: Wouldn't changing the setting in the main apache configuration provide an additional layer of security?

Comment: Not sure how it should make a big deal one way or the other.  Assuming the filesystem permissions are setup properly, you place the password database outside the web root and you have the standard  `<Files ~ "^\.ht"> ... Deny from all</Files>` block in place in your main config.

Answer (score 4):

No, using mod_auth and a .htaccess file is pretty much as simple as it gets if you want password protection.